# How does this code convert between bases?

Tags: c, converters

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void baseconversion(char s[20], int, int);
main()
{   
    char s[20];
    int base1, base2;
    printf("Enter the number and base:");
    scanf("%s%d", s, &base1);
    printf("Enter the base to be converted:");
    scanf("%d", &base2);
    baseconversion(s, base1, base2);
}

void baseconversion(char s[20], int b1, int b2)
{
    int count = 0, r, digit, i, n = 0, b = 1;
    for(i = strlen(s) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            digit = s[i] - '0' - 7;
        }
        else
        {
            digit = s[i] - '0';
        }
        n = digit * b + n;
        b = b * b1;
    }
    while(n != 0)
    {
        r = n % b2;
        digit = '0' + r;
        if(digit > '9')
        {
            digit += 7;
        }
        s[count] = digit;
        count++;
        n = n / b2;
    }
    for(i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I know this code converts chars to integers, but I've never seen it before, never used C.
If someone could explain a bit of what's going on with the conversions I'd appreciate it, thank you.
I understand that at some point the digits get reversed.

Comment: What is the purpose of this program? May you clarify it in a mathematical precise way?

Comment: The purpose is to convert Any base to Any base, for example 333 decimal to binary = 101001101

Comment: I'm sorry to be pedantic, but the purpose seems to be to convert a numeral system to another numeral system. You should use the right terms, because converting a base to another base is just something different.

Comment: regarding: `main()`  This will cause the compiler to output a warning message.  Note: there are only two valid signatures for main() `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: the `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers' (or EOF)  Should always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does it through two steps, the first one is converting the number into its decimal form, in this part:

```
for(i = strlen(s) - 1; i >= 0; i--)   //Start from right to left
{
    if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
        digit = s[i] - '0' - 7; //Get the integer equivalent to the letter
    else
         digit = s[i] - '0';    //Get the integer equivalent to the numerical character
    n = digit * b + n;   //Add the value of this character at this position
    b = b * b1;    //The value of the next character will be higher b times
}
```

Then it transforms the result to the desired base, in this part:

```
while(n != 0)
{
    r = n % b2;    //The remaining will be the rightmost value for the new base
    digit = '0' + r;   //Get the integer for the new digit
    if(digit > '9')
        digit += 7;    //Here the digit will be a letter
    s[count] = digit;
    count++;
    n = n / b2;    //Remove the rightmost digit to get the next one
}
```